# Expression Expected near if condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I keep getting expression expected error in VS near `if(isnullor ........`

```
if (value) {
  if (isNullOrUndefined(x.value) && isNullOrUndefined(x.value2)) {
    x.minMark + '-' + a + '*' 
    + x.b + ' ' + '+' + ' ' + x.c + ' ' 
    + val + '+' + ' ' + '*' + x.s 
    + ' ' + '+' + ' ' + ' ' + ' ' + x.val4;
  } else {
  }
} else {
  localeHelper.translate('module.reportSheet.inProgressMsg');
}
```

Comment: I believe you are missing the assignment. Also some formatting would be helpful

Comment: @Pijotrek Can you please explain?

Comment: @techno all those things you're adding together, you aren't assigning them to anything

Comment: Should be like `let potato = x.minMark + '-' + ...`

Comment: @Jayce444 okay... thanks

Comment: this is a prime example of why you should format your code

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided much context, but this part is suspect for a couple of reasons:

```
if(isNullOrUndefined(x.value) && isNullOrUndefined(x.value2))
{
  x.minMark + '-' + a+ '*'
  + x.b+ ' ' + '+' + ' ' + x.c+ ' '
  + val+ '+' + ' ' + '*' + x.s
  + ' ' + '+' + ' ' + ' ' + ' ' + x.val4
}
```

1. Because of Automatic Semicolon Insertion, you always want to put the `+` at the end of the previous line rather than the beginning of the next line, because at the beginning of the next line it can be the unary plus operator. With ASI, if adding a semicolon at the end of a line doesn't make the syntax invalid, it's usually added (but not always, the rules are slightly complicated).
2. You have an expression statement¹ there (a series of additions) whose result is never used for anything. Maybe you meant to use `x.minMark =` or `x.minMark +=` or something rather than `x.minMark +`.

---

¹ An *expression statement* is an expression used as a statement. JavaScript is *slightly* unusual in that it has an (almost) unlimited [expression statement](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-ExpressionStatement) (*any* expression can be used as a statement other than a couple of edge cases that would be ambiguous and have to be wrapped in a parenthesis expression), unlike some other languages (including Java) that have [limited ones](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8) that only allow some expressions (like method calls) to be statements.

Comment: Regarding point 2, The calculations are written to the webpage directly

Comment: @techno - The only way that would happen would be if you were using a **getter** to do the writing, which I doubt you are. In that code, the `{...}` isn't a JSX expression, it's a JavaScript block. The result of a JavaScript block isn't written to the page. The only time `{...}` is a JSX expression is when you're in a JSX context (for instance, `<X prop={value} />` or `<X>{value}</X>`).