# Nesting If statements in JSX

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm a beginner.I'm trying to nest two if statements in JSX

```
<span id={x.componentName + '-' + x.sampleGroupIdentifier + '-value-id'}
className='value bold'>
{isModerationFactorAvailable ? {!isNullOrUndefined(x.tailedGradient) ? "value1":"value2"}
x.minMark + '-' + thresholdMaxMark + '*'
+ x.tailedGradient + ' ' + '+' + ' ' + x.tailedIntercept + ' '
+ thresholdMaxMark + '+' + ' ' + '*' + x.primaryGradient
+ ' ' + '+' + ' ' + ' ' + ' ' + x.primaryIntercept :
[
localeHelper.translate('gradeAward.reportSheet.inProgressMsg')
]
}</span>
```

I keep getting the error ,what I'm i doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: [Again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64096990/expression-expected-near-if-condition#comment113344708_64096990), formatting would help a lot. Also, an explanation of what you're trying to do with those nested conditional expressions (they aren't "if statements") would help us help you. The main problem above is that you don't need to wrap something in `{}` if you're already in a JSX context.

Comment: There's a bunch of issues with this, not all of them JSX related. Swapping the curly braces with parentheses should fix the error in your question (i.e. `(!isNullOrUndefined(x.tailedGradient) ? "value1":"value2")`), but it still won't work cos your ternary syntax is wrong. The `x.minMark ...` stuff just starts out of nowhere, no colon before it

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The file extension is `.tsx`

Comment: @techno - ....and? What about it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder can't I use normal if else statements in typescript instead of the curly braces stuff ? We used to use curly braces in angular for value binding.Don't have any idea why its used here.

Comment: @techno - I suggest you step back from your current task and walk through some basic React/JSX tutorials, which will explain what `{...}` syntax in a JSX context is, why and how you use it, etc.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder okay.. will do

Answer (score 1):

<s>By using ternary operator, you have to supply the "else" branch with `:`.</s>

Reformatted your code a little bit, so you can see what's been missing:

Formatting makes it much more easy to read and debug your code. Ternarys commonly formatted like so:

```
isModerationFactorAvailable 
   ? !isNullOrUndefined(x.tailedGradient) 
      ? "value1"
      : "value2"
   : else branch
```

Comment: *"THIS ONE IS MISSING"* No, it isn't, it's just a lot further down, in a seemingly-unrelated place. Still, this is helpful for showing how to nest conditional expressions.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oops, you are right. Anyways, i leave my answer up because the formatting in OP's post is abysmal, and this should serve as an example for him.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely helpful for showing how to do it. :-)

Comment: Most linters forbid non-trivial expressions embedded in JSX for this reason anyway... it's unreadable pretty much no matter how you try to format it.

Comment: The file format is tsx. on changing the code as you provided the code identifier provided by VS is missing.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to valid comments / answers I would add a suggestion - don't put such big amount of if / else / ternary operators inside the markup. You are increasing the change of getting error like this and making your code harder to understand. You can use *Extract Variable* and *Extract Function* refactoring methods to make your (and your teammates) life easier. Something like this (I've removed some of your code, not sure what complete logic is):

```
  const id = `${x.componentName}-${x.sampleGroupIdentifier}-value-id`;
  const modFactorValue = !isNullOrUndefined(x.tailedGradient) ? "value1" : "value2";
  const inProgresMessage = localeHelper.translate('gradeAward.reportSheet.inProgressMsg');

  return (
    <span id={id} className='value bold'>
      {isModerationFactorAvailable ? modFactorValue : inProgresMessage}
    </span>
  )
```

Comment: what do you mean by that? code above will work fine for tsx.